# Hudson / Jenkins or Bamboo, Can you store build plans in svn / git?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, bamboo

We would like to keep a record of plans in svn or git so we can see what steps have changed in them over time.  Is this possible with Hudson/Jenkins, or Bamboo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins / Hudson has an [SCM sync configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) that will automatically commit hanges to your job configurations.  However, it currently only works with SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for bamboo, but hudson/jenkins jobs are XML files, so there is no reason you cannot store them in your favorite CM tool.